# why python decorator with argument requires 3 nested functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I have some code I want to improve. I got a suggestion to use a complex solution using `functools` which I could not understand.

Code Explanation: I am trying to create converter for Strings.
What I want to do here is to run some fixed code before a convert function is executed. However that execution depends on variable argument like country code and validation lengths for that string.

This is what I implemented taking inspiration from: https://www.scaler.com/topics/python/python-decorators/

I don't understand why we need 3 levels of functions nesting here just to implement decorator that requires arguments country_code and valid_lengths.

```
import functools
from collections.abc import Callable


class Number:
    def prevalidate(country_code: str, valid_lengths: list[int]):  # type: ignore
        def decorator(func: Callable):
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def wrapper(num: str, validate=False):
                if num.startswith(country_code):
                    num = num[2:]
                if validate and len(num) not in valid_lengths:
                    raise ValueError(f"{num} is not valid {country_code} number")
                return func(num, validate)

            return wrapper

        return decorator

    @staticmethod
    @prevalidate(country_code="DZ", valid_lengths=[13])
    def convert_dz(num: str, validate=False) -> str:
        return num[4:6] + num[-4:]

    ... # other similar methods

num = Number.convert_dz("W/2011/012346") # => 1012346
```

Comment: Note that there exist third party libraries like `decorator` which allow you to write decorators without the nesting of function definitions.

Comment: In order to explain something in a way which you can understand, it is required to know how much you already do understand. Do you understand why you need two levels for a decorator without arguments?

Comment: Thank you @Jasmijn and zvone. I am new to decorators. I now have some Idea how things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain each level first.

1. The outer level is the decorator factory, which produces your decorator based on some input values.
2. The second level is the decorator which is a function taking a function as argument and returns a new function which wraps the original function.
3. The inner level is the wrapper, which is the function which will replace the original function.

Now, you wonder why level 1. and 2. are not merged. Indeed they can be merged, but the three layers are motivated by the shortcut given by the `@` symbol. The `@deco` on a function `func` is equivalent to overwriting the name of the function with `func = deco(func)`, and `@deco_factory(args)` is equivalent to `deco = deco_factory(args); func=deco(func)`. So it is the `@` symbol which will only pass the function as single argument. Still, you can manually decorate functions, but you may confuse other python developers which are already used to the three layer design.

Edit:

I did not yet comment to your code example, but just explained the title question. Note, that every time you call the decorator factory with the same arguments, you are creating a new decorator. It would be better if you just reuse a single instance of the decorator. Moreover, if the input values of the decorator factory change the way your class `Number` behaves, you should better add those values to the class constructor, I mean the `__init__` method, and work with instances of `Number`.
Now, the implementation may not require a decorator, because adding `self.prevalidate(num)` at the beginning of each function is just a one-liner and is more explicit than the decorator, but there might be more ways to achieve it.